# Clang compiler flag -mbranch-protection=pac-ret+bti not generating bti instruction

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, arm, clang

I am experiencing a strange behavior of the clang compiler flag `-mbranch-protection=pac-ret+bti`. By looking into the documentation, the intended behavior appears to generate both `PAC (paciasp)` as well as `BTI` instructions. I am seeing `paciasp` instruction but not the `BTI` instruction in the assembly when compiling with `-mbranch-protection=pac-ret+bti`.

When compiling with `-mbranch-protection=bti`, the `BTI` instruction is being generated at the start of the function marking the valid entry point in a function as it should be.

This seems a bit unusual. `PAC` protects from ROP attacks, while `BTI` protects from JOP attacks. Is this a bug in the implementation? Any further clarification will be appreciated.

Note that `BTI` is supported from `armv8.5-a` and `PAC` from `armv8.3-a` onwards. The compiler will generate `nop` for the previous architectures. Clang version 12.0 is used in the test.

**Simple Code Example (test.c):**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    printf("%s", "Hello Main!");
}
```

**Compilation with PAC+BTI:**

$ clang -S -mbranch-protection=pac-ret+bti -arch arm64e -march=armv8.7-a -o test.s test.c

Output:

```
main:
  paciasp
  -----
  -----
  -----
  retaa
```

> Note: No BTI instruction generated in this case.

**Compilation with BTI:**

clang -S -mbranch-protection=bti -arch arm64e -march=armv8.7-a -o test.s test.c

Output:

```
main:
  bti c
  -----
  -----
  -----
```